# powershell ''find and replace'' with paths

Tags: powershell

im trying to make a powershell script that replaces some text and replace it. but i ran into a problem that i can move text just fine, but when the text has paths in the text powershell is looking for the path instead of replace the text.

is there a command that ignores the path written in the text and just replace it?

```
Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\accel8.ini
$data = foreach ($line in Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\accel8.ini)
{

 if ($line -like 'GlobalPath=G:\Accel40')
 {
    $line -replace 'GlobalPath=G:\Accel40' , 'GlobalPath=H:\'
    
 }
 else
 {
    $line 
 }
}
$data | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\accel8.ini
```

The error im getting The regular expression pattern:

> ```
> LocalPath=C:\users\%username%\Accel\Private is not valid.
>
> At C:\Users\(username)\Desktop\move accel.ps1:11 char:5
> +     $line -replace 'LocalPath=C:\users\%username%\Accel\Private' , 'L ...
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LocalPath=C:\us...%\Accel\Private:String) [], RuntimeException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the best thing to use on ini files is a dedicated ini module like [this one](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.3), you can do it fast with regex `-replace` like this:

```
$path    = Join-Path -Path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) -ChildPath 'accel8.ini'
$search  = [regex]::Escape('GlobalPath=G:\Accel40')
$replace = 'GlobalPath=H:\'

$data = switch -Regex -File $path {
    $search { $_ -replace $search, $replace }
    default { $_ }
}

$data | Set-Content -Path $path
```

Since the string to search has characters that have special meaning in regex like the backslash, you need to `[regex]::Escape()` that string first.

`switch -Regex -File $path {..}` reads the content of the file line-by-line and performs a regex compare to each line. If that compares to the `$search` string, the search string in the line is replaced, otherwise (the `default` option), the line is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use Non-Regex `.Replace()`:

```
Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\accel8.ini
$data = foreach ($line in Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\accel8.ini)
{

 if ($line -like 'GlobalPath=G:\Accel40')
 {
    $line.replace('GlobalPath=G:\Accel40','GlobalPath=H:\')
    $line
    
 }
 else
 {
    $line 
 }
}
$data | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\accel8.ini
```